# How to convert 7 digit timestamp in php?

Tags: php, rest, basecamp

I am working on an API and I get the below response. It's `basecamp 3 API`.

```
[
   'access_token' => 'BAhbB0kiAbB7ImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImUxZTk1NTYxMzdlZDIwYTQzZGEyYjk4NGU1NWEyYjM4Y2ExNWRlODQi'
   'expires_in' => 1209600
]
```

I don't know to which kind of date format `expires_in` belongs. I want to convert this timestamp to a standard DateTime string like below.

**Required Format**

`1209600` => `2018-06-23 14:09:01`

Comment: It looks like expiration date in seconds, not timestamp. After decoding access_token, do you get some create time? Because token is just Base64 encoded json, and does not seems to be full content in this question

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How do `1209600` and the given date from 2018 relate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What gets passed in `expires_in` is the interval of token validity in seconds. 1209600 in your example is equal to 14 days (`1209600 / (3600 * 24)`).

Here's one possible approach to convert this into real date:

```
$value = 1209600;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString( $value . ' seconds') );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Got it. I was thinking its julid date `unixtojd()`. Thanks @raina77ow